# Ansible's variables seem to vanish inside set_fact

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Is there some strange Ansible behaviour which means that inventory_hostname only works in certain contexts?

Here's the segment of the playbook I'm working on, and the first debug statement shows the right value, but `set_fact` then picks up an empty list, which is then picked up in the second debug task.

For some reason, the *exact same expression* behaves differently in `debug` from `set_fact`, and I can't see why. It's as if `inventory_hostname` is undefined in the `set_fact` task (and I even get a message suggesting that if I tag on a "| first" filter in both cases, as I eventually want to do.

```
- name: debug it
  debug:
    var: all_tagged_droplets.json.droplets | selectattr('name', 'equalto', '{{inventory_hostname}}') | list

- name: find the right droplet
  set_fact: 
    droplet: "{{ all_tagged_droplets.json.droplets | selectattr('name', 'equalto', '{{inventory_hostname}}') | list }}"

- name: debug it
  debug:
    var: droplet
```

Any pointers as to how to get data into a more sensible variable?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I was so silly.

I was attempting to evaluate `inventory_hostname` twice!! Because in the second case I need the `{{ ... }}` for the whole expression, I'd forgot to remove that from the variable.

The right answer was:

```
- name: debug it
  debug:
    var: all_tagged_droplets.json.droplets | selectattr('name', 'equalto', '{{inventory_hostname}}') | list

- name: find the right droplet
  set_fact: 
    droplet: "{{ all_tagged_droplets.json.droplets | selectattr('name', 'equalto', inventory_hostname) | list }}"

- name: debug it
  debug:
    var: droplet
```

See the expression in the `set_fact` line was fixed.